# Animation stops after first frame

Tags: java, android

I try to implement an explosion into my game but the animation stops after the first frame. If the player loses his health the explosion should be triggered. I made 3 Classes. Animation Class, an Explosion Class and GameActivity Class. I tried to only post the relevant pieces.
I searched the internet but I could not find a solution to my problem. So I am asking you if you maybe see my mistake and could help me. If more code is needed I will edit it of course. Maybe I am just overlooking something.

```
Animation Class{
public void setFrames(Bitmap[] frames)
{
this.frames = frames;
currentFrame = 0;
startTime = System.nanoTime();
}
public void setDelay(long d){delay = d;}
public void setFrame(int i){currentFrame= i;}

public void work()
{
long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;
if(elapsed>delay)
{
currentFrame++;
startTime = System.nanoTime();
}
if(currentFrame == frames.length){
currentFrame = 0;
playedOnce = true; }}

public Bitmap getImage(){
return frames[currentFrame];
}
public int getFrame(){return currentFrame;}
public boolean playedOnce(){return playedOnce; }}
```

This is the relevant part of the Explosion Class:

```
Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[numFrames];

//Bitmap has 4 * 4 frames
for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
if (i % 4 == 0 && i > 0) row++;
image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, (i - (4 * row)) * width,  
row * height, width*4, height*4);
}
animation.setFrames(image);
animation.setDelay(10);
}
public void animating() {
if (!animation.playedOnce()) {
animation.work(); }}
```

If the player loses all his health I call the explosion in GameActivity

```
if (player.getHealth() < 0) {
// player bitmap disappears
dissapear = true;
//game ends
gameEnded=true;
explosion = new Explosion(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   
R.drawable.images),player.getX(),player.getY()-10,9,9,25);
explosion.animating();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was my Game Activity. I had to change

```
if (player.getHealth() < 0) {
// player bitmap disappears
dissapear = true;
//game ends
gameEnded=true;
explosion = new Explosion(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   
R.drawable.images),player.getX(),player.getY()-10,9,9,25);
explosion.animating();}
```

to

```
if (player.getHealth() < 0) {
// player bitmap disappears
dissapear = true;
//game ends
gameEnded=true;
explosion = new Explosion(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   
R.drawable.images),player.getX(),player.getY()-10,9,9,25);
}

if (dissapear){explosion.animating();}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the main code I use to load the sprite sheet and grab the sprites:

```
     package com.animation.main;

    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Main extends JFrame{

BufferedImage sprite;

Animator player;

public Main(){
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    init();


}

private void init(){
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
    try {
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("insert your sprite sheet path here");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);

    ArrayList<BufferedImage> sprites = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

    sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(0, 16, 92, 109));
    sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(94, 16, 92, 109));
    sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(196, 12, 92, 115));
    sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(387, 5, 92, 115));
    sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(387, 5, 92, 115));
    sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(487, 5, 92, 115));
    sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(587, 5, 77, 115));

    player = new Animator(sprites);
    player.setSpeed(100);
    player.start();
}

Image dbImage;
Graphics dbg;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);

}


private void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if(player != null) {
        g.drawImage(player.sprite, 100, 100, null);
        player.update(System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
    repaint();

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
}
}
```

The parameters for the 'sprites.add(ss.grabSprite(0, 16, 92, 109));' code are the x and y value of your sprites top left corner on the spriteSheet and its width and height.

Run the code in the paintComponent class when the players health is less than or equal to 0. It would look something like this:

```
   private void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if(player != null && playerHealth <= 0) {
        g.drawImage(player.sprite, 100, 100, null);
        player.update(System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
    repaint();

}
```

This is the code I use for the spritesheet:

```
    package com.animation.main;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    public class SpriteSheet {

public BufferedImage spriteSheet;

public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage ss){
    this.spriteSheet = ss;
}

public BufferedImage grabSprite(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    BufferedImage sprite = spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
    return sprite;

}
```

THE grab sprite function and the BufferedImage sprite gets the sprite from the spriteSheet.

This is the BufferedImageLoader:

```
package com.animation.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class BufferedImageLoader {

 public BufferedImage loadImage(String pathRelativeToThis) throws     IOException{

    URL url = this.getClass().getResource(pathRelativeToThis);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
    return img;
}
```

}

This is the animator class:

```
  package com.animation.main;

  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class Animator {

ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames;

BufferedImage sprite;

private volatile boolean running = false;

private long previousTime, speed;
private int frameAtPause, currentFrame;



public Animator(ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames){
    this.frames = frames;
}

public void setSpeed(long speed){
    this.speed = speed;
}

public void update(long time){
    if(running){
        if(time - previousTime >= speed){
            // Update animation
            currentFrame++;
            try{
                sprite = frames.get(currentFrame);
            } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                currentFrame = 0;
                sprite = frames.get(currentFrame);
            }

            previousTime = time;
        }
    }
}
public void start(){
    running = true;
    previousTime = 0;
    currentFrame = 0;
    frameAtPause = 0;

}
public void stop(){
    running = false;
    previousTime = 0;
    currentFrame = 0;
    frameAtPause = 0;
}
public void pause(){
    frameAtPause = 0;
}
public void resume(){

}

}
```

Comment: The Android SDK does not support BufferedImage. I cannot use your code.